# Set search path for Postgres in a Rails app

Tags: postgresql, rails, heroku

I have a project in heroku. I have the URI that enables me to connect with the database in my external rails app. How do I change or set the search path in ruby code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it in your database.yml using the schema_search_path key with a string value

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  ...
  schema_search_path: 'schema1,public'
```

You can find out a bit more here: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/5aa2892b43-set-schema-search-path

Answer (score 0):

For the session, when inside/connected with psql, you can use [`SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html)`search_path =`. Or you can use the GUC and change the default for the user or database which will impact all connections from the user or to the specified database.

- `ALTER ROLE myUsername SET search_path = ...`
- `ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET search_path = ...`

Comment: can I set the path on my database.yml

Comment: No, but you can connect with a user/(ROLE) with the right search path, or alter the search_path for the database.

Comment: I am using ruby on rails.how do I do that? I have tried setting the search path but it has no effect, I keep on getting the public schema by default